# Add product to wishlist programmatically not working

Tags: admin, quote, wishlist, sales-order, programmatically

I am trying to add products from the admin create order screen straight into the users wishlist programmatically however it doesn't seem to be working.

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote');
$currentQuote = $quote->getQuote();
$customer = $currentQuote->getCustomer();

$items = $currentQuote->getAllVisibleItems();

$wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->loadByCustomer($customer->getId(), true);
Mage::register('wishlist', $wishlist);

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();
        $result = $wishlist->addNewItem($product, $buyRequest);

    if(is_string($result))
    {
        Mage::throwException($result);
    }
    $wishlist->save();

    Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'wishlist_add_product',
            array(
                'wishlist' => $wishlist,
                'product' => $product,
                'item' => $result
            )
        );

        Mage::helper('wishlist')->calculate();
}       

Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess("Quote sent successfully to customer!");

Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/sales_order/index'));
```

I'm not to sure what is going on. I am getting no errors in the log or exceptions being thrown however no products end up in the customer's wishlist.

Answer (score 1):

To add a product to customer's wishlist you simply need to initiate the wishlist model and call the **addNewItem** method passing the product object. This may help you

```
  $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
  $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

  $customer_id = 1;
  $product_id = 1;
  $customer->load($customer_id);
  $wishlist->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
  $wishlist->addNewItem($product->load($product_id));
```

You can use this codes wherever you want.

Comment: I guess this is already exactly what he is doing and more...

Comment: Yes I agree with you on that @7ochem, but he is creating a buy request for every item in the wishlist but I think the problem was with items not being added to wishlist